# My illustrator is hovering

Tags: adobe-illustrator

My AI is like hovering over my desktop, non of the panels latch and connect everything just hovers.  Ive messed with view, restarted the computer, nothing works.  [image]

Comment: Shut it down before the prophecy from Terminator becomes reality...

Answer (score 2):

`Window > Application frame`.

You probably mistakenly turned it off. I hate the darn thing :)

Comment: That was it thank you!  just a quick thing, I found it under Window>Application Frame.  Thanks again!